# Google Analytics draw chart with ga calls

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a chart via Google's Visualization line chart. I want that line chart to be based on my Google Analytic site stats. How would I do this?

```
script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["linechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Traffic', 'eCPM'],
      ['2004',  i.e ga:pageviews stats...,      1.25],
      ['2005',  1170,      5.2],
      ['2006',  660,       7.5],
      ['2007',  1030,      4.3]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, legend: 'bottom', title: 'Publisher Stats'});
  }
</script>
```

How would I do this? what do I have to add for this visualization chart to pull the data from my Google Analytic? To display on my chart.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/), it was created exactly for this purpose.

Here's what some example code might look like that queries Google Analytics and renders a Google chart:

```
var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
  query: {
    ids: 'ga:XXXX',
    metrics: 'ga:sessions',
    dimensions: 'ga:date',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday'
  },
  chart: {
    container: 'chart-container',
    type: 'LINE'
  }
});

dataChart.execute();
```

And this site has some great demos of the Embed API in action:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/